# Rails model naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, naming-conventions

I have an application which has `projects` and `users`.  I don't care about tracking the many-to-many relationships between `users` and `projects` but I am interested in tracking the many-to-one relationship between `projects` and a specific `user`, which is the project manager.  Ideally, I would like to create a column in the `projects` table called `projectmanager_id` and link it to a `user`.  However, rails convention dictates that I use `user_id` instead.  While this works, I feel the semantics aren't quite right.  Is there a way to have both?

One way I thought of is to create a `projectmanagers` table with `user_id` and `project_id` and have a `has_many :projects, :through=> :projectmanagers` in the `user` model, and `has_one :user, :through => :projectmanagers` in the `project` model.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if you keep the db column as user_id:
In your project.rb file:

> belongs_to :projectmanager, :foreign_key => "user_id", :class_name => "User"

And in your user.rb file still have:

> has_many :projects

---

Or if it's that you want your db column to be projectmanager_id

In your project.rb file:

> belongs_to :projectmanager, :foreign_key => "projectmanager_id", :class_name => "User"

In your user.rb file:

> has_many :projects, :foreign_key => "projectmanager_id", :class => "Project"

Comment: I like the second method.  I will try it.  Thanks!